# Update Linq to SQL Entities

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, repository-pattern

I have a repository pattern in my application, to implement the repository i use Linq to SQL, but apart from the automatically generated entities, i create my own entity classes to maintain abstraction.

The problem is when i try to update entities.
Since i fetch from the repositories the custom entities that i created, and not the ones that Linq to SQL created, all changes that i do to the fetch entities are not recorded by the Linq to SQL mechanism.

So when i write:

```
dbContext.SubmitChanges()
```

Nothing happens.

What can i do to solve this?

Thanks,
Arik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done a couple of projects with the same pattern that you are using. What I did was, before calling the `dbContext.SaveChanges()`, load in the corresponding generated entity or entities from the database and then copy over all the fields from the custom entities that were edited to those loaded entities.

Comment: I actually solved the problem already, and i solved it in the same way that you did.
Thank you :)